# Correct date formatting

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a php form which contains fields for start date and end date. I have already stored the rows in my mysql database and I would like to display the records within the range of start and end dates. I have a column called tdate of datetime value. My form displays the start and end dates in mm/dd/yyyy but mysql doesn't accept that.

Updated:-

```
$edate = $_POST['edate'] ?? '';
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'] ?? '';
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate));
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate));
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_master_tbl ";
$sql .= "WHERE tdate <= '$endDate' AND ";
$sql .= "tdate >= '$startDate' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$output = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print_r($output); }
```

Ok now it works on my form!

Comment: `strtotime()` is a PHP-function. You can't run a PHP-function in a SQL-query like that

Comment: Use prepared statements, and also use dates which are in an ISO format which MySQL recognizes.  This would be something like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson then what should my DATE() function look like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I used html's input tag and the date attribute displays date in that format. Plus I need it to display in m/d/Y as well

Comment: You need to convert the date to a proper format (like @TimBiegeleisen already suggested) in PHP first, something like: `$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate));` and then use `$endDate` in your query. Something like: `WHERE tdate <= '$endDate'`.

Comment: If the `tdate`-column in your db is a date-field, it will be stored in the `Y-m-d`-format, which is why you need to use that format to compare the dates. Normally, I would also suggest using Prepared Statements, but since you're actually creating the date variable through `date()` it will still be safe to use (even though it is a good practice to always use prepared statements).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited my code above and I'm now getting an error

Comment: You need to wrap the dates in quotes. Look at my example again, or better yet, look at the answer you've gotten. That's a better way...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the replies. Your answers are actually the closest I can get but now its displaying in the form of an assoc array and I don't want it to display like that

Comment: So don't display it like that? You can display it how ever you want it.

Answer (score 3):

Use prepared statements and convert your date strings into a format which can be used by MySQL as dates.  This answer is the MySQL centric one, which uses `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your `mm/dd/yyyy` strings into dates.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_master_tbl ";
$sql .= "WHERE tdate <= STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y') ";
$sql .= " AND tdate >= STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y')";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $edate, $sdate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The first parameter to `bind_param()`, namely `"ss"` tells PHP that we are binding two string parameters to the query.

An alternative to `STR_TO_DATE` would be to convert your PHP date strings into an ISO format in PHP.  In that case, you wouldn't need `STR_TO_DATE`, but using prepared statements would still be a good idea.

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors on the 2nd line, "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference" and "Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"

Comment: @SukritJaie I updated my answer again.  Thanks for your patience and FYI I am more of a MySQL person than PHP.

Comment: Yeah I'm new to them both actually. And now it's not showing anything, no errors but nothing is being displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo result directly from "mysqli_query". You should use this bellow code after "mysqli_query".

```
$output = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r( $output );
```

Comment: Well the errors are gone but it's doing not printing anything

Comment: @SukritJaie - That's because the query still fails.

Comment: I've edited my code. Let me know your "tdate" database field format please.

Comment: It's datetime. And now I can get it to output but its not in the correct format. i've updated my code above accordingly

Comment: You can use the output like this: $output["field_name"]